# Yahoo pipes compine Atom and RSS feeds

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes, atom-feed

I have a Yahoo pipe which gets lots of feed inputs, Atom and RSS.

Atom has a tag summary and RSS has a tag description. I managed to change summary to description with a loop and a string builder, because my pipe did not get the summary tag when I run it. But my problem is that the Atom feed has 2 or 3 link tags, one for the link of the page and others for photos.

My combined feed shows only one link (page's link) but I want somehow to get the second link that is the photo and store it to `item.image`. In my starting feed input component it shows only one link, and I guess that I can't parse the link with a regex because feed does not bring them with it.